# How to fix this Crash :java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: android, google-maps

I got crash when I work with googlemap I tried to search but I didnt got the correct answer !!
 I tried many suggested answers but it doesn't work with me !
It alwayes makes problem with GoogleApiClient.

```
public class SelectEndPoint extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
private static String TAG = "MAP LOCATION";
Context mContext;
TextView mLocationMarkerText;
private LatLng mCenterLatLong;
Spinner LocationSpinner;

/**
 * Receiver registered with this activity to get the response from FetchAddressIntentService.
 */
private AddressResultReceiver mResultReceiver;
/**
 * The formatted location address.
 */
protected String mAddressOutput;
protected String mAreaOutput;
protected String mCityOutput;
protected String mStateOutput;
EditText mLocationAddress;
TextView mLocationText;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE = 1;
Toolbar mToolbar;
double pinLatitude,pinLongitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_end_point);
    mContext = this;
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mLocationMarkerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationMarkertext);


    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    mResultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler());


    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        // If this check succeeds, proceed with normal processing.
        // Otherwise, prompt user to get valid Play Services APK.
        if (!AppUtils.isLocationEnabled(mContext)) {
            // notify user
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            dialog.setMessage("Location not enabled!");
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Open location settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Location not supported in this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "OnMapReady");
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            Log.d("Camera postion change" + "", cameraPosition + "");
            mCenterLatLong = cameraPosition.target;


            mMap.clear();


            try {


                Location mLocation = new Location("");
                 mLocation.setLatitude(mCenterLatLong.latitude);
                mLocation.setLongitude(mCenterLatLong.longitude);
                pinLatitude=mCenterLatLong.latitude;
                pinLongitude=mCenterLatLong.longitude;
                startIntentService(mLocation);
                mLocationMarkerText.setText("Lat : " + mCenterLatLong.latitude + "," + "Long : " + mCenterLatLong.longitude);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

     // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
     //  LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
     // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
     //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));







}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        changeMap(mLastLocation);
        Log.d(TAG, "ON connected");

    } else
        try {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    try {
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    try {
        if (location != null)
            changeMap(location);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}


protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();




}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    try {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            //finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void

changeMap(Location location) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Reaching map" + mMap);


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    // check if map is created successfully or not
    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        LatLng latLong;


        latLong = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLong).zoom(19f).tilt(70).build();

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        //mLocationMarkerText.setText("Lat : " + location.getLatitude() + "," + "Long : " + location.getLongitude());
        startIntentService(location);
        new AsyncGeocoder().execute(new AsyncGeocoderObject(
                new Geocoder(this),
                location,
                mLocationMarkerText
        ));



    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

}


/**
 * Receiver for data sent from FetchAddressIntentService.
 */
class AddressResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
    public AddressResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    /**
     * Receives data sent from FetchAddressIntentService and updates the UI in MainActivity.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {

        // Display the address string or an error message sent from the intent service.
        mAddressOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RESULT_DATA_KEY);

        mAreaOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_AREA);

        mCityOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_CITY);
        mStateOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_STREET);

        displayAddressOutput();

        // Show a toast message if an address was found.
        if (resultCode == AppUtils.LocationConstants.SUCCESS_RESULT) {
            //  showToast(getString(R.string.address_found));


        }


    }

}


/**
 * Creates an intent, adds location data to it as an extra, and starts the intent service for
 * fetching an address.
 */
protected void startIntentService(Location mLocation) {
    // Create an intent for passing to the intent service responsible for fetching the address.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FetchAddressIntentService.class);

    // Pass the result receiver as an extra to the service.
    intent.putExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);

    // Pass the location data as an extra to the service.
    intent.putExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, mLocation);

    // Start the service. If the service isn't already running, it is instantiated and started
    // (creating a process for it if needed); if it is running then it remains running. The
    // service kills itself automatically once all intents are processed.
    startService(intent);
}
```

the logcat is :

```
       java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zze com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zza.zza(android.content.Context, android.os.Looper, com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf, java.lang.Object, com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks, com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$OnConnectionFailedListener)"
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.zzarg(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.wneet.white.services.SelectPosition.buildGoogleApiClient(SelectPosition.java:471)
                                                                 at com.wneet.white.services.SelectPosition.onCreate(SelectPosition.java:156)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

thanx in advance..

Comment: Please just update your original post with any new information about your issue. Editing it will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: which google-playservices version you are using?

Comment: I use this version:        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0'